# Swift / iOS - Trigger scrollview on smaller screens

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, iphone-5

I have an app that I've built around a pretty tableview, and everything looks great on iPhone 6 and up.

When you select a cell on my table, you're presented with a details page with some content. The content fits perfectly on screen bigger screen sizes, but it needs to scroll on iPhone 5 or smaller.

I don't have anything fancy on the detailed view. Just a couple labels, text fields with small amts of text, and a button.

Can anyone offer any suggestions/direction on how to easily do this? I'm fairly confident I can get there with a little help.

Thank you!

**iPhone 5s:**

[image: iphone5s]

**iPhone 6 and up:**

[image: iphone6]

Comment: the question is kind of unclear -at least for me-, I'd suggest to add screenshot(s)...

Comment: @AhmadF uploading screenshots in just a moment.

Comment: What is tapped, and what should scroll?

Comment: @dmorrow I guess I should have asked for ideas / guidance on making everything fit onto the screen on iphone5

Comment: @AhmadF edited the main post to include screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're thinking of scrolling

> Bee Coffee
>
> Roasters: Roastery

To fit this on a smaller width screen you should probably just reduce the font size a little - maybe scale according to screen width?

If, say, `Font.font(name: "some font" size: 36)` looks good for you on a 4.7" iPhone (where screen width is 375pt) , but too large on a a smaller device, you could try scaling the font based on the screen width…

```
let fontSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 375  * 36
let font = Font.font(name: "some font" size: fontSize)
```

Alternatively you can set the minimum font size for a label in your storyboard…

[image]

Comment: Are you my hero today? My brain isn't working on all of these cold meds. I'll give this a try. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using constraints, be sure to constrain the trailing edge of the Labels as well - then at least Roastery will wrap to a third line and not crash into the border.  And, if you don't want it to wrap, you can limit to 2 lines and adjust your truncation settings.

I typically adjust all my layout sizes depending on screen width, not just font sizes.  So padding and other constraint constants are all scaled by a factor to account for smaller or larger than 375px.